# How should turning of SCNLight affect background color?

Tags: ios8, scenekit

I have a scene that consists of a few `SCNNode`s in front of a blue background. I would like to turn off the light when `SCNAction.rotate...` actions on the nodes have completed.

What I currently try is setting `SCNLight.color` to `SKColor.blackColor()`. This turns my nodes into black surfaces but leaves the blackground in blue.

Is this a feature (of SceneKit) or a bug (presumably in my code)? If it is the former how could I switch the light "completely" off (preferably with an animation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a background color, that is going to be independent of the lighting in the scene, it's just a background color. You could animate it to also be black when you turn of the light if you wanted to.

The scene (`SCNScene`) also has a `background` material property that you can set the `contents` of. This material property should be affected by the light in your scene.

Comment: I can set `background` to a string (specifying the location of an image file) but setting it to any `SKColor` results in a white background (i.e. the value is apparently not recognized). Do you also have an idea on how this remaining obstacle can be mastered?

Comment: Animating the background color also to black turned out to be the best solution so far.